# ACAccountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:completion always showing permissions prompt

Tags: ios, facebook, social-framework

As the title suggests, I'm having an issue with the method ACAccountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:completion. I expect this method to only prompt the user for permission the first time it is called for my app, but it is being shown *every* time.

Is there some way of checking whether the user has granted permission so I don't have to request it? Or is there some other kind of magic that will stop this behaviour?

I find this very odd, since in an earlier version of the same app, the behaviour was as I expected - it only prompted for permission on the first call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question. Hopefully somebody will find this useful some day.

What seemed to be causing the problem was a mismatch between the permissions available to my app, in particular the basic read permissions, and the permissions I was requesting. While my app's Facebook page showed 'email' as a basic read-permission, it was requesting 'basic_info'. Once I changed the permission to 'email', the app asked once and didn't do so again.

Comment: You are a legend!!! Thank you so much. But how an earth did you figure this out? Also looking at the Facebook Developer "My Apps" page, where do you find permissions required for your app? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Heh I'm glad it helped somebody! It's a while ago, so the details are pretty hazy, but I remember reading something about the basic permissions requirements having changed on FB's side, and seeing that my app was still using the old approach. This was after a lot of brute-force / hacking and running in circles. Would be pretty helpful with some kind of warning in these situations...

Comment: Oh and I found the permissions in the specific app, under 'Status and Review'.